# Handlebars helper inheritance?

Tags: handlebars.js

Is it possible for a Handlebars helper to inherit from another Handlebars helper? for example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('DateHelper', function(date, format) {
    if (!date) return;
    var formatted = format;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<time>' + formatted + '</time>');
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('shortDate', function(date) {
    // I want to something like this..
    return Handlebars.helper.DateHelper(date, moment(value).format('D MMM YYYY'));
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "helper inheritance"? Helpers actually nothing more than a functions bounded to template's context. You can do with them everything what can be done with plain JS functions, like using constructors, prototypes, etc. Please, provide an example of inheritance you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware it is not directly possible to inherit from one Handlebars helper to another, however it is possible with an ordinary constructor function, for example:

```
var DateHelper = function HandlebarsDateHelper(date, format) {        
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<time>' + format + '</time>');
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('shortDate', function(date) {
    if (!date) return;
    return new HandlebarsDateHelper(date, moment(value).format('D MMM YYYY'));
});
```